# Cubase No Audio

Tags: audio, element, audio-recording

I am attempting to install Cubase Elements 10.5 'stay at home trial but fail to get any audio.
I have followed numerous guides online about shuffling various Gb files around (surely thats the installer job) but still nothing.
All audio mapping shows as connected.
When testing eg using the Production > Blues Rock Production (so its not even setup), for each Channel I get the error message:

> The current preset or project was created with a previous version of HALion Sonic SE. If you modify the preset using new features of this trial version a previous version might not be able to load it or the preset might sound different

if I just click ok and load the project it seems to play, but no audio or output levels show.
I am getting nowhere with Steinburg 'Support', raised a support request and this is just ignored.
I have been trying to get this working for about a month and installed several times.

**VST Connections**

[image]

**Audio Device and Driver**

[image]

The application is in focus when it fails to provide audio, not sure where to make it play in background.

**Screenshots of fault:**

[image]

**Chose a project as test, but when loading each of the channels shows this error,**

[image]

**I click ok to make it load:**

[image]

**Press play, no sound**

[image]

**but see it playing here:**

[image]

Comment: citation formatting

Answer (score 0):

Attach a screenshot of your VST connections in Cubase to help others diagnose your system.

- Ensure you have latest drivers for your audio card etc.
- Ensure your operating system (or any other background/foreground app) is not using the outputs you have selected in Cubase.
  as they may not be multi-client.
- ASIO compatible hardware is recommended.
- Ensure background audio is enabled in Cubase if the application is not in focus.

Confirm that you have followed at least the steps above in any further replies. Specify your level of experience with computer audio in general, so that further information is relevant to you :-)

Comment: Thanks for tips on improving post, edited and added above